# Enable blackhole storage engine for mysql without recompiling mysql

Tags: mysql, blackhole

Is it possible to enable/add the Blackhole storage engine to an existing MySQL server instance if it doesn't currently exist in the show engines command?  MySQL 5.1 CentOs 6.5 Linux.  Documentation seems poor in this regard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blackhole is distributed as a plugin on CentOS 6.x series. To enable it in mysql you need to do this as a superuser:

```
INSTALL PLUGIN blackhole SONAME 'ha_blackhole.so';
```

After that, check it with:

```
SHOW ENGINES;
```

Comment: Old post but thanks for this.  Confirmed it solves related issues with MariaDB 10 in a Docker container on Synology NAS.